# Appending Two arrays in Laravel get() Query Builders

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have to queries in Laravel. First, to get a single post. Second, to get all comments. My problem is, I cannot append correctly the two arrays output of the `get()` in Laravel Query Builders.

When I tried to join them, the post appeared 3 times since I have 3 comments for that post. So instead of joining I tried to `array_push` them. Now the output is like this.

```
[
    {
    "id": 44,
    "image": "9178hello.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit!",
    "address": "internet",
    "lat": 45.435,
    "long": 2312.3,
    "created_at": "1 hour ago"
    },
    [
        {
            "comment": "my comment.... my comment 1.....",
            "created_at": "2015-01-11 17:24:27"
        },
        {
            "comment": "my comment.... my comment 2.....",
            "created_at": "2015-01-11 17:24:29"
        },
        {
            "comment": "my comment.... my comment 3.....",
            "created_at": "2015-01-11 17:24:30"
        }
    ]
]
```

How can I make it as:

```
[
    {
    "id": 44,
    "image": "9178hello.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit!",
    "address": "internet",
    "lat": 45.435,
    "long": 2312.3,
    "created_at": "1 hour ago",
    "comments" : { 
           list all the comments here...
         }
    }
]
```

Here's the Query:

```
    $disaster = Disaster::where('name', '=', $name)->first(['id']);

    $post =  DB::table('posts')
                ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'posts.location')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
                ->select('posts.id', 'posts.image', 'posts.description', 'locations.address', 'locations.lat', 'locations.long', 'posts.user_id', 'users.firstname', 'users.lastname', 'posts.created_at')
                ->where('posts.disaster_id', '=', $disaster->id)
                ->where('posts.id', '=', $id)
                ->get();

    if (empty($post)) {
        return ['error' => 'no post found'];
    }

    $post[0]->created_at = Carbon::parse($post[0]->created_at)->diffForHumans();

    $comments = DB::table('comments')
                  ->select('comment', 'created_at')
                  ->where('post_id', '=', $post[0]->id)
                  ->get();

    array_push($post, $comments);

    return $post;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this do

```
$array = array_merge($post, array('comments' => $comments));
```

Docs: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
This will append the comment with `comments key` to the post array.

Since you are using Laravel why not make use of **Eloquent** relations? Just make a one to many relation between post and comment and get them any way you want.

Read [Laravel Eloquent Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)